# Hive Job failed with return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask and Query Performance

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive

Every day I have a hive job that compute some aggregations for each quarter of hour for two months of data. It's resulting in submitting something like 5760 jobs to Tez.

The job failed with the following error in the stderr :

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
```

The error could occurred after 2300 - 2500 tez jobs. Just before this error, There is a lot of the following logs in the Yarn Logs :

`2015-12-10 21:53:35,286 INFO [TezChild] task.ContainerReporter: Sleeping for 200ms before retrying getTask again. Got null now. Next getTask sleep message after 2000ms`

And the execution time of a single job is dramatically expending, from 20s to 100s.

I don't have any clue about my issue and I can't find anything else in yarn, Hadoop, hive, or tez logs (no exceptions, nothing marked as an error).

So I have two questions :
Where can I find more information in logs or something else that could help me to resolve this issue ?

Currently we use :

- The latest version of Azure HDInsight 3.2
- Jobs are submitted to the cluster with the C# SDK
- Hive jobs use tez

**Question 2 :**
I'm pretty sure that we do not do our aggregations in a good way. For each aggregation (i.e for each quarter), we should retrieve the precedent value of a row. I hoped to use the LAG function, but we could not pass a predicate for finding the precedent value (we need the precedent value that is not greater than the current value). So we could not find an other way than generate a query for each quarter that we need to compute.
Is someone know how we can do that in a single hive query ?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Best regards

Comment: In our cluster (HDP) this *"return code 1"* usually means that YARN launched the App Master (container #1) but had not enough resources to launch a sufficient number of TEZ executor containers to process the DAG => the AppMaster waits => until time-out. Investigate `tez.session.client.timeout.secs` and `tez.session.am.dag.submit.timeout.secs` and so on.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to increase the values of `tez.session.client.timeout.secs` & `tez.session.am.dag.submit.timeout.secs` but it does not change anything. I have also tried to decrease the container size for having more available containers. No changes

Comment: Can you share the code and possibly some information about the data set?

Answer (score 4):

Cause: 
This issue occurs when Kerberos is enabled and "hive.server2.enable.doAs" property in Hive is set to true. When this property is set, the query looks for "Run as end user instead of Hive user is true", which means the end user has to be present locally in every Node Managers. The above error occurs when the end user is not present locally.

Solution: 
To resolve this issue, create the end user running the Hive queries locally or present it through AD/LDAP.

Comment: This got me on the right path to fix the issue. When I looked closer i noticed i was setting `tez.queue.name` to a different username than the one i was actually using to connect to hive.

Answer (score 0):

It can come from multiple reason, I had the same issue at works and it seems like  it was a user directory permission issue.

Basically, When you run a query it uses your user directory, certain operations create a temporary file and your /user/ directory is used to store temp files and then deletes them once the query is finished, it appears to be failing due to no permissions on user directory.

Check with your admin if you have that directory created and you have access to it.

More info about the error are here:

```
SD.TME.BIGDATA.INFRASTRUCTURE-SUPPORT-PROD ERROR: Prepare error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask: Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=userId, access=WRITE, inode="/user/userId":StrutherM:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x Us
```

Answer (score -5):

If you are running for many dates it will happen, Reduce the dates, if you really need 3 months data, use union all and divided into 3 months.